# dig works only when specifying a nameserver

Tags: networking, dns

I have a Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop installation. I am unable to access internet or reach any servers by name. The DNS lookup is failing. DNS Servers are Windows DCs 10.0.1.22, 10.0.1.21 and two Cisco Umbrella proxy appliances 10.0.6.70,10.0.6.67

```
root@sdbuilder-NU591:/etc/network/interfaces.d# nmcli dev show | grep DNS
IP4.DNS[1]:                             10.0.6.67
IP4.DNS[2]:                             10.0.6.70
```

The dig command works only when I specify the DNS server.

```
root@sdbuilder-NU591:/home/sdbuilder# dig google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

root@sdbuilder-NU591:/home/sdbuilder# dig google.com @10.0.6.70

; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> google.com @10.0.6.70
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 10355
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 6, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.                    IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.             300     IN      A       142.251.116.100
google.com.             300     IN      A       142.251.116.101
google.com.             300     IN      A       142.251.116.102
google.com.             300     IN      A       142.251.116.113
google.com.             300     IN      A       142.251.116.138
google.com.             300     IN      A       142.251.116.139

;; Query time: 16 msec
;; SERVER: 10.0.6.70#53(10.0.6.70)
;; WHEN: Tue Dec 26 13:08:48 CST 2023
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 135
```

The IP is set using DHCP and I am getting the search domain. However, it's not resolving any host on the domain.

```
root@sdbuilder-NU591:/home/sdbuilder# cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by NetworkManager
search example.com
nameserver 127.0.0.53

root@sdbuilder-NU591:/home/sdbuilder# ping server1
ping: server1: Temporary failure in name resolution

root@sdbuilder-NU591:/home/sdbuilder# ping server1.example.com
ping: server1.additech.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

If I use `dig google.com @10.0.6.70`, `tcpdump` is capturing traffic but without using the DNS server IP, I am not getting any traffic using `tcpdump -n udp port 53`

```
root@sdbuilder-NU591:/home/sdbuilder# tcpdump -n udp port 53 -v
tcpdump: listening on enp3s0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
13:16:05.308404 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 41787, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 79)
    10.0.6.58.40227 > 10.0.6.70.53: 12769+ [1au] A? google.com. (51)
13:16:05.326976 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 58695, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 163)
    10.0.6.70.53 > 10.0.6.58.40227: 12769 6/0/1 google.com. A 142.251.116.138, google.com. A 142.251.116.139, google.com. A 142.251.116.100, google.com. A 142.251.116.101, google.com. A 142.251.116.102, google.com. A 142.251.116.113 (135)
^C
2 packets captured
3 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
1 packet dropped by interface
root@sdbuilder-NU591:/home/sdbuilder#
```

`systemd-resolved is disabled and inactive`. Here is the output of some network conf files:

```
root@sdbuilder-NU591:/home/sdbuilder# ls -al /etc/resolv.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 72 Dec 26 12:23 /etc/resolv.conf

root@sdbuilder-NU591:/home/sdbuilder# cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

root@sdbuilder-NU591:/home/sdbuilder# cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
```

There is no file in `/etc/network/interfaces.d`

If I enable and start  `systemd-resolved`, it's still no resolving names.

```
Dec 26 13:26:00 sdbuilder-NU591 systemd-resolved[4652]: Using system hostname 'sdbuilder-NU591'.
Dec 26 13:26:00 sdbuilder-NU591 systemd-resolved[4652]: Another process is already listening on TCP socket 127.0.0.53:53.
Dec 26 13:26:00 sdbuilder-NU591 systemd-resolved[4652]: Turning off local DNS stub support.
Dec 26 13:26:00 sdbuilder-NU591 systemd[1]: Started Network Name Resolution.
```

```
root@sdbuilder-NU591:/etc/network/interfaces.d# cat /etc/systemd/resolved.conf
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#
# Entries in this file show the compile time defaults.
# You can change settings by editing this file.
# Defaults can be restored by simply deleting this file.
#
# See resolved.conf(5) for details

[Resolve]
DNS=10.0.1.22
FallbackDNS=10.0.1.21
#Domains=
#LLMNR=no
#MulticastDNS=no
#DNSSEC=no
#DNSOverTLS=no
#Cache=no-negative
#DNSStubListener=yes
#ReadEtcHosts=yes
```

Looks like dnsmasq is also running.

```
root@sdbuilder-NU591:/etc/network/interfaces.d# netstat -tulpn | grep ":53 "
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      902/dnsmasq
tcp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                    LISTEN      902/dnsmasq
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53              0.0.0.0:*                           902/dnsmasq
udp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                                902/dnsmasq
```

Comment: If you want to use systemd-resolve you have to turn off dnsmasq as it takes port 53 that local resolver of systemd-resolve needs. Other option is not to use systemd-resolve and manually provide nameservers in /etc/resolv.conf file: `nameserver 10.0.1.22 nameserver 10.0.1.21`

Comment: @Terrance `dig google.com @10.0.1.22` also works. The DHCP is providing those name servers. I didn't edit anything. `10.0.6.70` and `10.0.6.70` are DNS forwarders. If the traffic is for the internal domain, they send it to the DCs and if it's the internet, they will block based on Cisco Umbrella filters.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see in your output that you had `dnsmasq` running as well.  But, the `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` file is manually edited and not supplied by DHCP.  Anyways, glad you got it solved.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, this was resolved using stopping `dnsmasq` service and using the `systemd-resolved` service.